# How to create a connect with Sql database

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to connect my sql database to my php but there is an issue with the syntax of the "created function to the database". Can someone help fix it.

Here is the code

```
<?php

class Database {

    public $host = DB_HOST;
    public $user = DB_USER;
    public $pass = DB_PASS;
    public $dbname = DB_NAME;

    public $link;
    public $error;

    private function connectDB(){


// here is the issue

        $this -> link new mysqli($this -> host, $this -> user, $this -> pass, $this -> dbname);

        if(!$this->link){

            $this->error = "connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
    }

} 

?>
```

Comment: How are you calling that function? That is a private function so you can't call it from outside the class. And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: `$this -> link new mysqli` This is a syntax error.

Comment: Where is your `=` sign?

Comment: You should see _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "new"_ - https://3v4l.org/f2tUb - Please check at least the TL;DR section at https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting

Comment: $this -> link = new mysqli